# Why does this Listbox only displays the 1st 2 rows of the spreadsheet and doesn't update to show additional rows after data entry?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, data-entry

So I recently managed to figure out how to finally add data to multiple worksheets depending on what value the combo box was selected.

E.g. Worksheets PL531e, PL931 & PL968. If you selected PL931 from the combobox, inputed your data into the text boxes and clicked the "Save Data" button it would add the inputted data to the worksheet "PL931" & vice versa if you picked PL968 or PL531e it would save the inputted data directly into the relevant worksheet.

I have a listbox at the bottom of my userform, which currently displays the data only in the 1st 2 rows (Headers & 1st row of data).

If there is no data in the worksheet and I click the "Save Data" button the listbox will automatically update and show me the data I've entered; however if I decide to add additional data it will not display any other rows bar rows 1 & 2 whereby row 1 is the headers & row 2 is the 1st row of data.

I know the data is being saved to the spreadsheet because when I close the form itself, and the view the relevant spreadsheet, the data is there, just the listbox doesn't want to display anymore rows than the 1st two.

Can anyone explain to me how I can modify my code to fix this issue (See code below)?

Note: Please ignore the layout and messiness of the code, I prefer working to get the code working before then looking for more efficient replacements.

```
Option Explicit
Dim iExit As VbMsgBoxResult
'Dim updateRow As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = [Counta(Overview!D:D)]
With DataEntry

.TestNo.Value = ""
.NeuronID.Value = ""
.DateCode.Value = ""
.TextBox4.Value = ""
.TextBox5.Value = ""
.TextBox6.Value = ""
.TextBox7.Value = ""
.TextBox8.Value = ""
.TextBox9.Value = ""
.TextBox10.Value = ""
.TextBox11.Value = ""
.TextBox12.Value = ""
.TextBox13.Value = ""
.TextBox14.Value = ""
.TextBox15.Value = ""
.TextBox16.Value = ""
.TextBox17.Value = ""
 
If ComboBox1.Value = "PL531e" Then
    TextBox9.Visible = True
    TextBox10.Visible = True
    TextBox11.Visible = True
    TextBox12.Visible = True
    TextBox13.Visible = True
    TextBox14.Visible = True
    TextBox15.Visible = True
    TextBox16.Visible = True
    TextBox17.Visible = True
   
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 17
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL531e!A1:Q" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL531e!A2:Q2"
    End If
        
    Label10.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 9)
    Label11.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 10)
    Label12.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 11)
    Label13.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 12)
    Label14.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 13)
    Label15.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 14)
    Label16.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 15)
    Label17.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 16)
    Label18.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 17)
    
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PL931" Then
    TextBox9.Visible = True
    TextBox10.Visible = True
    TextBox11.Visible = True
    TextBox12.Visible = True
    TextBox13.Visible = False
    TextBox14.Visible = False
    TextBox15.Visible = False
    TextBox16.Visible = False
    TextBox17.Visible = False
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 13
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL931!A1:M" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL931!A2:M2"
    End If
       
    Label10.Caption = Sheets("PL931").Cells(1, 9)
    Label11.Caption = Sheets("PL931").Cells(1, 10)
    Label12.Caption = Sheets("PL931").Cells(1, 11)
    Label13.Caption = Sheets("PL931").Cells(1, 12)
    Label14.Caption = ""
    Label15.Caption = ""
    Label16.Caption = ""
    Label17.Caption = ""
    Label18.Caption = ""
    
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PL968" Then
    TextBox9.Visible = True
    TextBox10.Visible = True
    TextBox11.Visible = False
    TextBox12.Visible = False
    TextBox13.Visible = False
    TextBox14.Visible = False
    TextBox15.Visible = False
    TextBox16.Visible = False
    TextBox17.Visible = False
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL968!A1:J" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL968!A2:J2"
    End If
    
    Label10.Caption = Sheets("PL968").Cells(1, 9)
    Label11.Caption = Sheets("PL968").Cells(1, 10)
    Label12.Caption = ""
    Label13.Caption = ""
    Label14.Caption = ""
    Label15.Caption = ""
    Label16.Caption = ""
    Label17.Caption = ""
    Label18.Caption = ""
    
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PN410X" Then
    TextBox9.Visible = True
    TextBox10.Visible = True
    TextBox11.Visible = False
    TextBox12.Visible = False
    TextBox13.Visible = False
    TextBox14.Visible = False
    TextBox15.Visible = False
    TextBox16.Visible = False
    TextBox17.Visible = False
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PN410X!A1:J" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PN410X!A2:J2"
    End If
      
    Label10.Caption = Sheets("PN410X").Cells(1, 9)
    Label11.Caption = Sheets("PN410X").Cells(1, 10)
    Label12.Caption = ""
    Label13.Caption = ""
    Label14.Caption = ""
    Label15.Caption = ""
    Label16.Caption = ""
    Label17.Caption = ""
    Label18.Caption = ""
    
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PN510" Then
    TextBox9.Visible = False
    TextBox10.Visible = False
    TextBox11.Visible = False
    TextBox12.Visible = False
    TextBox13.Visible = False
    TextBox14.Visible = False
    TextBox15.Visible = False
    TextBox16.Visible = False
    TextBox17.Visible = False
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 8
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PN510!A1:H" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PN510!A2:H2"
    End If
    
    Label10.Caption = ""
    Label11.Caption = ""
    Label12.Caption = ""
    Label13.Caption = ""
    Label14.Caption = ""
    Label15.Caption = ""
    Label16.Caption = ""
    Label17.Caption = ""
    Label18.Caption = ""
    
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "GL100" Then
    TextBox9.Visible = True
    TextBox10.Visible = True
    TextBox11.Visible = False
    TextBox12.Visible = False
    TextBox13.Visible = False
    TextBox14.Visible = False
    TextBox15.Visible = False
    TextBox16.Visible = False
    TextBox17.Visible = False
    

    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "GL100!A1:J" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "GL100!A2:J2"
    End If
    
    Label10.Caption = Sheets("GL100").Cells(1, 9)
    Label11.Caption = Sheets("GL100").Cells(1, 10)
    Label12.Caption = ""
    Label13.Caption = ""
    Label14.Caption = ""
    Label15.Caption = ""
    Label16.Caption = ""
    Label17.Caption = ""
    Label18.Caption = ""

End If

End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range

If ComboBox1.Value = "PL531e" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL531e")
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PL931" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL931")
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PL968" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL968")
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PN410X" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PN410X")
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "PN510" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PN510")
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "GL100" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GL100")
End If
Set AddNew = sh.Range("A6536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = TestNo.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = NeuronID.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = DateCode.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 3).Value = TextBox4.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = TextBox5.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 5).Value = TextBox6.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox7.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox8.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = TextBox9.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 9).Value = TextBox10.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 10).Value = TextBox11.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 11).Value = TextBox12.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 12).Value = TextBox13.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 13).Value = TextBox14.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 14).Value = TextBox15.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 15).Value = TextBox16.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 16).Value = TextBox17.Text

End Sub

Private Sub RefreshListBox()
Me.lstDatabase.Clear
Dim ListRange As Range

End Sub

Private Sub reset_Click()
iExit = MsgBox("Confirm if you want to exit", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Data Entry Form")

If iExit = vbYes Then
Unload Me
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Label1.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(2, 1)
ComboBox1.List = [Products!A2:A7].Value

Label2.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 1)
Label3.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 2)
Label4.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 3)
Label5.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 4)
Label6.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 5)
Label7.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 6)
Label8.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 7)
Label9.Caption = Sheets("Overview").Cells(4, 8)

TextBox9.Visible = False
TextBox10.Visible = False
TextBox11.Visible = False
TextBox12.Visible = False
TextBox13.Visible = False
TextBox14.Visible = False
TextBox15.Visible = False
TextBox16.Visible = False
TextBox17.Visible = False

ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0


End Sub
```

Comment: A lot of irrelevant lines of code, able only to confuse us... I did not have enough patience to read all your code. Did you check what value `iRow ` takes? Please, put break lines on the rows where you have different expectations and see what's happening. Eventually, press F8 to run code line by line and see where is the wrong value.

Comment: Pretty hard to debug when your code is not "efficient"...

Comment: You need to explain a bit why `iRow` always references `Overview` and not any of the other sheets that you set the listbox source to.

Comment: I did mention to ignore the layout and messiness of the code, excel vba isn't my forte and I typically start out my coding just to get it working and then I'll simplify it later.

Although I've now fixed the bug. now so I'll post the answer.

Comment: @TimWilliams Figured out the problem with irow was I wasn't declaring which sheet it was counting in 'iRow = [Counta(Sheetname!A:A)]' fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the code - Turned out I needed to add the following line

```
iRow = [Counta(SheetName!A:A)]
```

Placement of said line is located here:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim iRow As Long
With DataEntry
 
If ComboBox1.Value = "PL531e" Then
TextBox9.Visible = True
TextBox10.Visible = True
TextBox11.Visible = True
TextBox12.Visible = True
TextBox13.Visible = True
TextBox14.Visible = True
TextBox15.Visible = True
TextBox16.Visible = True
TextBox17.Visible = True

Label10.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 9)
Label11.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 10)
Label12.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 11)
Label13.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 12)
Label14.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 13)
Label15.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 14)
Label16.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 15)
Label17.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 16)
Label18.Caption = Sheets("PL531e").Cells(1, 17)

iRow = [Counta(PL531e!A:A)]
.lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 17
.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50"

If iRow > 1 Then
    .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL531e!A1:Q" & iRow
Else
    .lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL531e!A2:Q2"
End If
```

Additionally I had to add a Sub reset() with the following code:

```
Sub reset()
Dim iRow As Long
With DataEntry

If ComboBox1.Value = "PL531e" Then
iRow = [Counta(PL531e!A:A)]

    If iRow > 1 Then
        DataEntry.lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL531e!A1:Q" & iRow
    Else
        DataEntry.lstDatabase.RowSource = "PL531e!A2:Q2"
    End If
```

After this was added the issue was sorted, I additionally found a issue which involved the headers in the listbox displaying the column header names themselves E.g. Column A, B, C etc. instead of the TestNo, NeuronID, Date Code etc. I solved this by simply deleting the following line of code:

```
.lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
```

Not gonna paste the entire code all fixed as those basic fixes are literally copied/pasted  in their relevant sections just instead of PL531e its PL931, PL968 etc.

Edit: Following on from what @Tim Williams suggested, Me.Controls("Textbox" & i) I ended up changing the **Textbox9.Visible = True etc..** section to the following using both Me.Controls and the tagging property:

```
Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control

For Each oneControl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(oneControl) = "TextBox" Then
With oneControl
    Select Case .Tag
        Case "typeA"
            .Visible = True
            .Value = ""

        Case "typeB"
            .Visible = Not (ComboBox1.Value = "PN510")
            .Value = ""

        Case "typeC"
            .Visible = ((ComboBox1.Value = "PL931") Or (ComboBox1.Value = "PL531e"))
            .Value = ""

        Case "typeD"
            .Visible = (ComboBox1.Value = "PL531e")
            .Value = ""
    End Select
End With
End If
Next oneControl
```

Comment: Good to see you fixed your issue.  You can definitely shorten your code considerably using some loops and e.g. `Me.Controls("Textbox" & i)`

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip, vba definitely isn't my forte but any small tips to shorten the code afterwards are definitely helpful, especially for the 100's of if statement for combobox & Textboxes/label.captions